# Convergence of a sum of two power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

If I have that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}$ converges, then obviously $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$ converges, where $z,z_0,a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $z \neq z_0$.

Does the converse hold?

Namely, if we have that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$ converges, than it always follows that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$ converges and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}$ converges?

I really think that it is not true, but I'm stuck in looking for a counterexample. Any hint would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: I know that in the general case (generic complex series) if we have that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (z_n+w_n)$ converges, then it is not necessary true that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} z_n$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} w_n$ converge.

As an example: $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+0i)$ diverges, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-n+0i)$ diverges, but $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} [(n+0i)+(-n+0i)]$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Statement is a little confusing.  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}$ won't converge for $z=z_0$, except trivial case.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited it. $z$ and $z_0$ are two fixed different complex values.

Comment: Is convergence for all $z\ne z_0$?

Comment: No. $z$ is a fixed number, different from $z_0$, such that $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$ converges.

Comment: There's probably some condition like if it converges at two points, one on the inner boundary of an annulus, the other on the outer boundary of the annulus, then it converges absolutely on the inside of the annulus, and then your reversed statement holds. Though there's probably some additional conditions needed, because the proof of the analogous statement for power series on a disc fails because $a_n(z-z_0)^n$ and $b_n(z-z_0)^{-n}$ may not tend to 0 just because their sum tends to 0. And just assuming that they do tend to 0 would be pointless, since that's almost what we want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that $z-z_0=c$ a constant, let $a_n=\frac{1}{c^n}$ and $b_n=-c^n$, both series diverge, but the series of pairwise sums $=0$.  I don't think this is what you had in mind.